# I have a linked trie returning false instead of true. What errors can be fixed in the code?

Tags: python, trie

I have a trie that isn't doing as expected. The code for it is given below:

```
class Trie:
    def __insert(node, item):
        # This is the recursive insert function.        
        if len(item) == 0:
            return None

        elif node == None:
            newnode = Trie.TrieNode(item[0])
            newnode.follows = Trie.__insert(newnode.follows, item[1:])
            return newnode

            # return Trie.TrieNode(item[0], follows=Trie.__insert(node, item[1:]))

        elif node.item == item[0]:
            node.follows = Trie.__insert(node.follows, item[1:])

        else:
            node.next = Trie.__insert(node.next, item)

    def __contains(node, item):
        # This is the recursive membership test.
        if len(item) == 0:
            return True

        elif node == None:
            return False

        elif node.item == item[0]:
            return Trie.__contains(node.follows, item[1:])

        else:
            return Trie.__contains(node.next, item)

    class TrieNode:
        def __init__(self, item, next=None, follows=None):
            self.item = item
            self.next = next
            self.follows = follows

        def __str__(self):
            return "TrieNode(" + str(self.item) + ")"

    def __init__(self):
        self.start = None

    def insert(self, item):
        sentinel = item + "$"
        self.start = Trie.__insert(self.start, sentinel)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        sentinel = item + "$"
        return Trie.__contains(self.start, sentinel)


def main():
    t = Trie()
    t.insert("cow")
    t.insert("cat")
    # t.insert("rat")
    # t.insert("rabbit")
    # t.insert("dog")

    print("cow" in t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are the rules for the code:

**For the __insert function:**

> 1. If the key is empty (i.e. no units are left in the key), return `None` as the empty node.
> 2. If the node is `None` then a new node is created with the next unit of the key and the rest of the key is inserted and added to the `follows` link.
> 3. If the first unit of the key matches the unit of the current node, then the rest of the key is inserted into the `follows` link of the node.
> 4. Otherwise, the key is inserted into the `next` link of the node.

**For the __contains function:**

> 1. If the length of the key is 0, then report success by returning `True`.
> 2. If the node we are looking at is `None` then report failure by returning `False`.
> 3. If the first unit of the key matches the unit in the current node, then check membership of the rest of the key starting with the `follows` node.
> 4. Otherwise, check membership of the key starting with the `next` node in the trie.

Inserting one item is okay; for example, it gives `True` when it checks for `cat` if it only had `cat` in there.

It's a different story with multiple strings, though. The main function gives `False`, instead of `True`, as it should. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the `__insert` or `__contains` functions. Is there any way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `__insert` method should *always* return a node when `item` is not empty. Yet, in the case that `node` is not None, it returns None. But in that case is should return `node`.

So add `return node` at the end of this method.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back to this answer?

Comment: I actually want to fit with the criteria in the question, so I'll consider it as a last resort. For now, though, do you have a solution that fits with the instructions above?

Comment: As far as I can see that follows the instructions. Which of the rules do feel this breaks?